# Access docker container by name in windows

Tags: windows, docker

I create 2 windows container(I try to run windows application, not docker for windows in VM). And want to add link from a to b.

```sh
docker run -d --name a imageA
docker run -d --link a:a --name b imageB
```

I can access a from b by ip, but access by name is not working

Comment: Also I check C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts. It's not contains any records.
And I didn't see env variables related to container link.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a docker network first:**

```
docker network create myNetwork
```

**Connect both the containers(container1 and container2) to the network as following:**

```
docker network connect myNetwork container1

docker network connect myNetwork container2
```

**Run the docker network inspect command**

```
docker network inspect myNetwork
```

**Enter the bash of container1 as following:**

```
docker exec -it container1 /bin/bash
```

**Now, you can ping container2 by name:**

```
ping container2
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help.
And I use windows container. Probably it's bug in docker for windows

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov,  sorry for being away for a while. Have you tried using Docker Compose? Create the services inside Docker compose file and it does establish the network between containers automatically. I am hoping that behavior is consistent for Windows containers too.